# Php exec ffmpeg not running in background

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I am trying to start a ffmpeg process from a php script and I know it has been asked a lot of times but I tried many solutions and none of them seem to work, each time the php script never finishes unless I kill the ffmpeg process. At the moment I am using this script which indeed starts ffmpeg and writes info in the designated files but the php script is loading forever.

What am I missing?

```
$cmd = 'cd cache && ffmpeg -y -i "rtsp://stream" -r 20 -f image2 a%6d.jpg >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &';

exec(sprintf("%s > %s 2>&1 & echo $! >> %s", $cmd, 'log.txt', 'error.txt' . '.pid'));
```

A little more info: I am running FFMpeg 0.6.5, PHP 5.3.3 on CentOS 6.5

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `> /dev/null &` instead of `2>&1 &`

This will execute `$cmd` in the background without PHP waiting for it to finish.

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thanks but that still doesn't work, the page loads forever, if I stop the page from loading the FFmpeg process will indeed keep running in the background...but it has to continue executing the php script.

Comment: I found what was causing the proble, your answer was indeed correct but because the command had the cd cache && it didn't work, when I changed the && to ; it finally ran in the background. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed this using [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup).

So instead of:

```php
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4 > /dev/null &'
```

I used this:

```php
$cmd = 'nohup ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4 > /dev/null &'
```